# Can I instantiate an Exception and hold onto it for later, and avoid the costly stack trace if it's never thrown?

Tags: java, exception

The situation I'm thinking of using this is within a mutlithreaded app. Suppose my main thread (we'll call this Prime) needs to kick off another thread (we'll call it Daemon) to do something in the background.

The Daemon thread can be launched from several different places in the Prime thread, and if the Daemon thread runs into an error, I want to know which piece of code in the Prime thread originally launched the Daemon thread which failed.

So suppose in the Prime thread I create a `new Exception("some message")`, hand it to the Daemon thread (e.g. in its constructor), and then start the Daemon thread.

If the Daemon executes without errors, the Exception never gets used, and I'd like to avoid paying the cost of tracing the stack.

On the other hand, if the Daemon has an exception occur, I want it to be able to use the Exception from the Prime thread along with the Daemon's own exception to help when debugging. The stack trace from the Prime thread's Exception would indicate where the Daemon was spawned, and the stack trace from the Daemon would indicate where in the Daemon the problem was encountered.

If I do this, will I have to pay the processing cost of the Prime thread's Exception for every case, or just the case where the Daemon thread encounters an error and subsequently looks at the Prime thread's Exception's stack?

Comment: The exception's stack trace is constructed when the exception is constructed. So yes, you have to pay the cost of construction whether or not it is thrown. However, I would expect that the cost of constructing the thread would be far greater.

Comment: @AndyTurner You should convert that comment to an answer.

Comment: What about adding the caller to the activate method and make it possible to read that value out of the deamon?

Answer (score 1):

The exception's stack trace is filled in when the exception is constructed. If you look at the constructors of `java.lang.Throwable`, they all look [something like](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/Throwable.java#249):

```
public Throwable() {
  fillInStackTrace();
}

public Throwable(String message) {
  fillInStackTrace();
  detailMessage = message;
}
```

etc. where `fillInStackTrace()` is the method which builds the stack trace. So yes, you have to pay the cost of stack trace construction whether or not it is thrown.

However, I would expect that the cost of constructing the thread would be far greater.

Comment: `However, I would expect that the cost of constructing the thread would be far greater.` Do you have any references supporting this? Would it matter how tall the stack is, or are threads orders of magnitude more expensive than stack traces?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your intention you want to preserve some part of a stacktrace in the place where you are creating a new thread for further debugging.

Of course, you can just call `new Exception().getStackTrace()` but it might be your bottleneck because traverse across all the stack is not cheap. If you are on a HotSpot you can use a private API to get access to one StackTraceElement which is a most common case and usually enough for debugging/logging purposes. `sun.misc.SharedSecrets.getJavaLangAccess().getStackTraceElement()` is that API but it will unavailable in JDK9. In JDK9 you will be able to use [Stack-Walking API](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/259).

Here is a benchmark

```
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS)
public class StackTraces {

    @Benchmark
    public StackTraceElement[] getStackTrace() {
        return new Exception().getStackTrace();
    }

    @Benchmark
    public StackTraceElement getFast() {
        return sun.misc.SharedSecrets.getJavaLangAccess()
                                     .getStackTraceElement(new Exception(), 2);
    }
}
```

And the results:

```
Benchmark                  Mode  Cnt   Score   Error  Units
StackTraces.getFast        avgt    5   2.799 ± 0.066  us/op
StackTraces.getStackTrace  avgt    5  14.014 ± 0.290  us/op
```

P.S. You can create Exception without any stacktrace (very cheap) by overriding `fillInStackTrace`. Moreover, if you have a throwing an Exception on a fast path, HotSpot can cache it and omit creating stacktraces. You can disable this behavior by using the option `-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow`

```
new Exception() {
    @Override
    public synchronized Throwable fillInStackTrace() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: You've missed the point of my question entirely. I know how to get stuff from the stack trace, I'm asking if I can avoid the **cost** of building the stack trace *unless it's actually needed*.